# Send Email Exception Error Message

Tags: java, email, jsp, servlets

I have the following `doPost` in my servlet that inserts a record into the postgres db and then sends an email to the user about the purchase. I tested the insert and it works perfectly but when I try to add the code for the send email an exception error happens and I don't understand why.

I even tested the send email function in a standard a lone java application and it works fine. Heres my code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Start");
        HttpSession s = request.getSession(true);
        String firstName = (String) s.getAttribute("firstName");
        String lastName = (String) s.getAttribute("lastName");
        String email = (String) s.getAttribute("email");
        String creditCard = (String) s.getAttribute("cCard");

        if (s.getAttribute("bookingCart") != null) {
            System.out.println(firstName);
            if(firstName == null || lastName == null || email == null || creditCard == null) {
                response.sendRedirect("MasterController?confirmBooking=true&error=Data+not+valid");
                return;
            }
            bookingDTO booking = (bookingDTO) s.getAttribute("bookingCart");
            bookingsDAO bookingsDAO = new JDBCBookingsDAO();
            bookingsDAO.confirmPaymentBooking(booking.getId() , email, firstName, lastName, creditCard);
            System.out.println("Booking updated");
            String msg = "Dear Customer,\n Thnk you for Using Our website \n Please use link below to confirm your Booking\n"+
                         " ";
             // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
              String to = "brice2nic3@gmail.com";

              // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
              String from = "brice2nic3@gmail.com";

              // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
              String host = "smtp";

              System.out.println("Proterpies");
              // Get system properties
              Properties properties = System.getProperties();
              System.out.println("Booking updated1");
              // Setup mail server
              properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
              System.out.println("Booking updated2");
              // Get the default Session object.
              Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
              System.out.println("Booking updated3");
              try{
                  System.out.println("Booking updated4");
                 // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                 System.out.println("Booking updated5");
                 // Set From: header field of the header.
                 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                 System.out.println("Booking updated6");
                 // Set To: header field of the header.
                 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                          new InternetAddress(to));
                 System.out.println("Booking updated7");
                 // Set Subject: header field
                 message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
                 System.out.println("Booking updated8");
                 // Now set the actual message
                 message.setText("This is actual message");
                 System.out.println("Booking updated9");
                 // Send message
                 Transport.send(message);
                 System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
              }catch (MessagingException mex) {
                 mex.printStackTrace();
              }
            s.removeAttribute("bookingCart");
            s.setAttribute("bookingCart", null);
            s.removeAttribute("bookingAmount");
            s.setAttribute("bookingAmount", null);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Booking not updated");
            response.sendRedirect("MasterController?retHome=true");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("redirected to masterController");
        response.sendRedirect("MasterController?Message=Booking+Successful");
    }
```

and my exception message is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not setting your smtp username, password and port number to system properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of `NoClassDefFoundError` is that a particular class is not available in Classpath. Third party API 
`mail.jar` should be under `/WEB-INF/lib` under your web application

You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute

Comment: javax.mail should be present in j2ee.jar, as he is working on servlet based app, j2ee.jar should be present on server ...

Comment: thnks mate that was the problem :)